# Can SQL injection be achieved through $_FILES variables?

Tags: php, html, sql, file, code-injection

I'm just going through a current project adding the necessary code to prevent SQL injection, XSS etc. However I was wondering how easy it would be to execute SQL injection via a file upload?

Does any one have any knowledge in this area?

Comment: That depends. Are you sending `$_FILE` data to the SQL server?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you executing any SQL in connection with your file upload? If yes, can you show the code you are using to do that?

Comment: @You: He should send data to SQL to make SQL injection possible. Am I wrong?

Comment: @genesis: Well, yes, he has to. But I've never really seen the need to do that myself.

Comment: That's true, but I think he would not ask if he would know that he don't need SQL ;)

Comment: To help some of you guys out... let's say I store the image path in the database using $path . $_FILES['name']; (just a quick example of course I'd properly sanitize this before it happened).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should sanitize any user-supplied input. This includes $_FILES. For example, if you store the uploaded filename in a database, this could be exploited by an attacker.

Comment: Okay that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered correctly by qbert220 but I wanted to add an additional note.

You should ensure that the file is the correct MIME type, otherwise if your expecting an image to be uploaded and then displayed, if "nasty user" uploads a php script it could be ran on your server and do whatever you could do with the script.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application needs. If you are doing an image gallery and want to tag uploaded images, you may want to add the data for the images to the database. For this, you may need to put in the database the contents of `$_FILES['image']['name']`, then a SQL injection it's possible if you don't escape its value.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done if you're for example inserting filename into DB.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES ('".$_FILES['upload']['name']."');"); //this is injectable
```

Answer (score 0):

Never think if given input can be used for SQL injection, escape any variable that is send to the database. Same applies for XSS when you are outputing variable. Do not trust $_SERVER or any other superglobal. Do not trust your variables as well (those initialized in the code).